# saving splitted database in respective folders

Tags: r

I have a data frame and want to make the list of data frames on the basis of values in one column. and then i want to save the files respectively in respective folders.

i want to create folders like local , regional and save the subset of local , regional in respective folders

tried various approach but not working

```
mtcars

data <- mtcars

region <- unique(mtcars$carb)

path<-"C:/local/visio/Desktop/test1/"
region<-factor(region,levels=c(1,2,3,4,6,8),
                labels = c("Local","Regional","outsider","Top cities","near by","villager"))

for(k in region){
  #dbList <-  split(data, f=data$carb, drop = TRUE)
  
  dbList<-list()
  dat2<- paste0(k,"_database")
  dbList[[dat2]] <- data[data$carb == k,]
  dat2_1 <- data.frame(dbList[[dat2]])
  
  path1 <- dir.create(paste0(path,region[k]))
  write.csv(path1,dat2_1,".csv")
}
```

Comment: You have at least two problems: 1. `dat` is not declared. Did you suppose `data` instead? 2. `path` variable is not assigned but used in `dir.create()`

Comment: `country` vector is not defined as well

Comment: And you reassign `path` variable in your loop thus replacing the initial value of it. Use another variable name instead

Comment: i wanted to know how to do it , tried many times but not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255200/discussion-between-samrr-tr-and-asd-tm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this:

```
dir.create(path, recursive = T) # You can skip this line if you prefer 
# using commented command inside the loop

for(k in region){
  #dbList <-  split(data, f=data$carb, drop = TRUE)
  
  dbList<-list()
  dat2<- paste0(k,"_database")
  dbList[[dat2]] <- data[data$carb == k,]
  dat2_1 <- data.frame(dbList[[dat2]])
  
  path2 <- paste0(path, "/", k)
  dir.create(path2, showWarnings = F)
  # or dir.create(path2, recursive = T, showWarnings = F)
  write.csv(dat2_1, paste0(path2,"/",k,".csv"))
}
```

Some explanation:

From documentation for `dir.create()`:

> recursive  logical. Should elements of the path other than the last be
> created? If true, like the Unix command mkdir -p.